# I am new to githib and having issues with merging branches that result in deleted

Tags: github

I am new to github and have been having an issue with merging files and need advice on how to best avoid the issue.

Here is a simple example of what we are experiencing. We have a master repository on Github. it contains 
master/ index.html

Then Dev1 pulls it down to his local and creates a new branch and creates a new file so now Dev1 has 
dev1-branch / index.html foo.html

Dev 2 also pull down the original master to his local and creates a new branch 
dev2-branch / index.html bar.html

Dev1 pushes his branch to GitHub and runs a merge so now GitHub master is 
master / index.html foo.html

Dev2 then pushes his branch to Github and runs a merge but now the master on Github is 
master/ index.html bar.html

foo.html is deleted.

I would have assumed that Github would have held onto both files? So master would be 
master / index.html foo.html bar.html

Or did Dev2 need to pull the master and merge it to his dev2-branch before pushing?

Any advice on best practices to avoid this would be great.

Answer (score 2):

It's a good practice to run `git pull` before you `git push`.

In your case,  Dev1 merges his branch onto master on github. Dev2 doesn't have this new additions on his/her local. Hence the error when he pushes.

You could read more about `git pull` [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/syncing/git-pull)

You can go through the tutorials to know more about the best practices also [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials)